# Pandas and h5py load the same data (ndarray) differently

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, hdf5

I have a file in [HDF5](https://hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) format.  It was created using the HDF5's C++ API using these:

```
struct SignalDefH5
{
    char  id   [128];
    char  name [ 64];
    char  units[ 16];
    float min;
    float max;
    hvl_t tags; /* This right there does not work in Pandas... */
};

struct TagDefH5
{
    char  tag [ 64];
    char  desc[256];
};
```

If I load the file using [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/), I get this:

```
>>> import h5py
>>> hfile = h5py.File('test.h5', 'r')
>>> signals = hfile['/signals']
>>> signals[0]
('id1', 'a pressure', 'bar', 0.0, 300.0, ['Pressure'])
>>> type(signals[0][5])
numpy.ndarray
```

However, if I use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) to load the same file, I get this:

```
>>> store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
>>> store.root.signals
/signals (Table(179,)) ''
  description := {
  "id": StringCol(itemsize=128, shape=(), dflt='', pos=0),
  "name": StringCol(itemsize=64, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1),
  "units": StringCol(itemsize=16, shape=(), dflt='', pos=2),
  "min": Float32Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=3),
  "max": Float32Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=4),
  "tags": StringCol(itemsize=64, shape=(), dflt='', pos=5)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (234,)
>>> store.root.signals[0]
('id1', 'a pressure', 'bar', 0.0, 300.0, '\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0f\x1e\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\xba\nVT\xd1!\xa7\xdd\xb0\xe3\x9a\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00@\xecR\x1f\xa2\x7f\x00\x00}B\x178\x96\xa4u\xe6\xb0\xdd\x7f\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x01')
>>> type(store.root.signals[0][5])
numpy.string_
```

Clearly there is a problem with the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) way: *what did I do wrong?*

- Python version is 2.7.5.
- h5py version is 2.4.0.
- Pandas version is 0.16.0.
- PyTables version is 3.1.1.

Comment: well, how did you create the file?

Comment: well pandas is not compatible with h5py it may work but if u created in pandas that makes a difference; so it does matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas HDF5 support uses `PyTables`. This provides a meta-data layer on top, which is itself (meaning PyTables) on top of raw HDF5. `h5py` is pretty-raw HDF5.

So the sub-field is not know to pandas, e.g. what it actually is. You are getting a raw-bytes string.

Nested structures like these are simply not supported. These don't map nicely to pandas structures. Further by creating this file in raw HDF5 you are missing lots of meta data that pandas needs to interpret the data.

Simply use `PyTables/pandas` to write your data. You can then *maybe* reverse engineer this format in c++.

Comment: I find it very odd that the raw `HDF5` can guess the type fine but `PyTables` fails and there is not way to tell `PyTables` how to get it right...

Comment: You are using an usupported nested type of structure.

Comment: It appears to be supported both by h5py and the C++ API. Is it just Pandas that does not support it? Is there really no way to tell it what data it is? Not trying to be awkward, just trying to understand.

Comment: if PyTables does not support it, no. Not everything in the spec is actually supported by PyTables. Mainly as were not implemented, or they don't map well to higher level structures.